# How to change a division hash function according to bucket size

Tags: c, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I'm working on a school project, in which I have to implement rehashing. I don't know which method would be the best for this case, but I was thinking about hashing the actual number like this:

```
int hash (struct Table *temp, int key)
{
    int test = 3; // here would be the buckets size +1 but the function below cannot return it
    return key % test;
}
```

The init function:

```
void init (struct Table *temp, int buckets)
{
    if (buckets == 0) // make sure I allocate something
        buckets = 2;

    temp->entries = 0;
    temp->size = 1;

    while (temp->size < buckets) // ensure buckets is a power of 2
        temp->size *= 2;

    printf("post temp->size: %d\n", temp->size);

    temp->buckets=(struct Node **) calloc(temp->size, sizeof(struct Node *));
}
```

This is how I insert to the table and rebuild the table if neccessary:

```
struct Node *insert (struct Table *temp, int key)
{
    struct Node *temp2 = search(temp, cislo);

    if (temp2 != NULL) // if temp2 doesnt exists
        return temp2;

    // I extend the table if neccessary
    while (temp->entries >= 0.5 * temp->size) 
        rebuildTable(temp);

    // add the new entry
    int h = hash(temp, key);
    temp2=(struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp2->key=key;
    temp2->next=temp->bucket[h];
    temp->bucket[h] = temp2;
    temp->entries++;

    return NULL;
}

void rebuildTable (struct Table *temp)
{
    struct Node **oldBucket, *oldHash, *temp2;
    int oldSize;
    int h, i;

    oldBucket=temp->bucket;
    oldSize=temp->size;

    /* create a new table and rehash old buckets */
    init (temp, oldSize * 2);
    for (i=0; i < oldSize; i++) 
    {
        oldHash=oldBucket[i];
        while(oldHash)
        {
            temp2=oldHash;
            oldHash=oldHash->next;
            h=hash(temp, temp2->key);
            temp2->next=temp->bucket[h];
            temp->bucket[h]=temp2;
            temp->entries++;
        }
    }

    free(oldBucket); //
}
```

The main problem is that the "test" variable in the hash function can only be bigger by one than buckets in the init function, otherwise the program fails, SEGMENTATION FAULT. I have to change it somehow so it could dynamically work based on the size of the buckets. For this input:

```
int arr[] = {0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 1, 8, 15, 22, 29, 36, 43, 50, 57, 64, 71, 78, 85};
    init(temp, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/4; i++)
        insert(temp, arr[i]);

    showTable(temp);
```

I get this output:

```
post temp->size: 2
post temp->size: 4
post temp->size: 8
post temp->size: 16
post temp->size: 32
post temp->size: 64
Numbers in the 0. bucket: // the number mod 3 == 0
78 57 42 0 21 63 15 36
Numbers in the 1. bucket:
85 64 43 49 28 7 1 22
Numbers in the 2. bucket:
71 50 35 14 56 8 29
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem is. `int hash (struct Table *temp, int key)` That shows the `hash` function receives the `Table` which contains the `size`. Why can't you use that?

Comment: I just spent 15 minutes writing and translatimg this. I have already tried what you mentioned, but for some reason I thought the ouput was not correct ... I really need a break ... btw thank you

Comment: So you are all good now?

Comment: Yeah, I think so ... still I have to test the whole program, but thank you once again =)